# Winform User Control - How to get a reference of property and not a copy

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, user-controls

In a program I wrote, I came up with functionality for a User Control, so I decided to break it out into its own project/DLL. The control consists of two buttons and a panel.  When I use the DLL, however, I am missing a critical piece of functionality - I can no longer change the `AutoScrollPosition` of the panel! My hunch is that I'm getting a copy, not a reference to the property when I go to set it... So here's an idea of the code:

```
// this works when the user control is native to my project
panelContainer.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, myVal + 1);

// this doesn't work when the user control is Referenced in my project    
FromDLL.panelContainer.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, myVal + 1);
```

I can change other properties on the `FromDll.panelContainer`, such as the name, but I can't change AutoScrollPosition.  Other properties between the two are exactly the same (`AutoScroll = false`, etc...).  To top it off, when I create Setter method in the DLL, the calls work:

```
// Call from project to set DLL's reference to native panel
FromDLL.SetMainPanel(nativePanel);

// Now this works after the call to SetMainPanel
FromDLL.panelContainer.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, myVal + 1);
```

Any ideas on why I'd be getting a copy of the AutoScrollPosition instead of a reference?

Comment: Is panelContainer some win form standard class or it is your wrapper?

Comment: Good question - panelContainer is simply a WinForms `Panel`.

Comment: FromDLL.panelContainer is just a field or property?

Comment: `FromDLL.panelContainer` is a field. I've made it protected/public depending on the implementation to no avail.

Comment: Hmm, no, nothing to do with AutoScrollPosition.  The DLL is simply using the wrong Panel object reference.  Probably one that it created itself, it isn't the one that you are looking at.  Those other properties don't work either, it is just more visible for AutoScrollPosition because you can actually see the scrollbar not moving.  Try BackColor for example, that's very visible.  Exactly why the DLL code is using the wrong reference is not visible at all in your snippets.  Other than explicitly handing it the correct one of course works.

Comment: Properties aren't actually variables. Internally, they are a Get and a Set function. Sometimes just one of these two, if they're read-only or write-only. So you simply _can't_ put a reference straight to it; they're not real objects. You can never rely on what happens inside those get/set functions, in terms of copying or duplicating to new objects.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check up your control client size, versus **System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.AutoScrollMinSize**. Also, make sure **your System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.AutoScroll** is true and take into account **System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.AutoScrollMargin** with **System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.AutoScrollOffset**. It's possible that you simply did not understand the concept, as happens with some members in the past.

This is the article with minimalistic and clear explanation of matter:
https://web.archive.org/web/20141229163946/http://bobpowell.net/understanding_autoscroll.aspx.

See also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.aspx.